# Error: File ended while scanning use of \tabu@collectbody

Tags: tabu, kile

Kile returns the error "File ended while scanning use of \tabu@collectbody" when I add this to my code.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | c | c | } 
    \hline
    \underline{Variable} & \underline{Value}\\
     $B(\Lambda^{+}_{c}\longrightarrowpK^{-}\pi^{+})$ & 0.0623 \cite{mt}\\
     $B{\phi\longrightarrowK^{+}K^{-}$ & 0.492 \cite{mt}\\
     $E_{sig}$ & 4.5127$\%$\\
     $N_{norm}$ & 1 468 435 \cite{bpal}\\
     $E_{norm}$ & 16.564$\%$ \cite{bpal}\\
     \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
```

I've tried messing around with different ways to make the table but they all seem to return the same/similar errors.

This code has a missing {} bracket. When I fix that, My citations all get the error "undefined". I also get these errors:
Undefined control sequence \end{tabu}
Double superscript \end{tabu}

Comment: You have an unmatched `{` in the line `$B{\phi\longrightarrowK^{+}K^{-}$ & 0.492 \cite{mt}\\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit I decided to post an answer.

The first problem, which causes the `File ended while scanning use of \tabu@collectbody` error, is the unbalanced `{`. This extra `{` makes TeX scan the file searching for a matching `}` which is not found, thus `File ended`.

The second error, `Undefined control sequence`, is because of the `\longrightarrowpK`. [I couldn't find anywhere in the internet a command called `\longrightarrowpK`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22longrightarrowpK%22), thus I assume it is a typo, and what you actually meant is `\longrightarrow pK` (with a space). The same goes for `\longrightarrowK` on the next line.

As for the citations being undefined, it is probably a problem with the `.bib` file or with running BibTeX. I suggest reading [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/134574) or asking a new question providing a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Fixing these two problems and adding a basic preamble, it works:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | c | c | }
    \hline
    \underline{Variable} & \underline{Value}\\
     $B(\Lambda^{+}_{c}\longrightarrow pK^{-}\pi^{+})$ & 0.0623 \cite{mt}\\
     $B\phi\longrightarrow K^{+}K^{-}$ & 0.492 \cite{mt}\\
     $E_{\mathrm{sig}}$ & 4.5127$\%$\\
     $N_{\mathrm{norm}}$ & 1 468 435 \cite{bpal}\\
     $E_{\mathrm{norm}}$ & 16.564$\%$ \cite{bpal}\\
     \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```